# ¿Porqué usamos el tiempo verbal presente para acciones futuras con algunos verbos?

Tags: tiempos-verbales

Tratando de entender porqué usan tiempos verbales distintos al que supuestamente se debería usar en otro idioma me dí cuenta que en Español hacemos lo mismo. Por ejemplo con el verbo ir. Cualquiera diría "voy a la cancha mañana" y no "iré a la cancha mañana". O "mañana como milanesas". En lugar de "mañana comeré milanesas".

¿Porqué usamos el tiempo verbal presente para acciones futuras con algunos verbos? ¿Existe alguna regla para cuándo es válido y cuándo no?

Comment: Esto es una suposición, de acuerdo a lo que pasa en otros idiomas y como el español funciona, que al utilizar "mañana" para ubicar la acción en el tiempo, puedes poner el resto de la oración en tiempo presente, es decir, tienes la oración "voy a la cancha", y la ubicas en el tiempo diciendo "ahorita", "mañana", "la próxima semana". y te queda "voy a ir a la cancha ahorita/mañana/al rato". Espero alguien tenga una respuesta más completa.

Comment: En inglés se usa también a veces el presente como futuro (pero mucho menos que en español). En alemán se usa también (y todavía más que en español).

Comment: Mi profesor de español argentino siempre me enseñaba que el uso del presente para acciones futuros indica un mayor nivel de certeza que el tiempo verbal futuro. *Mañana como en casa de mi mama* = no hay duda. *Mañana comeré en casa de mi mama* = hay una duda pequeña

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al igual que ocurre en otros idiomas, el tiempo presente suele usarse con sentido futuro cuando se trata de acciones programadas:

- Tengo una semana ocupada: mañana **voy** a la cancha, pasado **tengo** examen y el jueves **salgo** de viaje.
- Mi dieta es bien variada: mañana **como** milanesas, pasado me **toca** pasta y el jueves **tengo** postre permitido.

Comment: La NGLE (23.3.2c) lo llama “presente prospectivo” o “presente pro futuro”.